# angular js $http request to localhost - status code = -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, localhost

I am have been attempting to do a simple GET request to a simple server on localhost:3000.  I always get a status = -1 indicating a timeout.

My code is as follows:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/features/123',
  timeout: 5000
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log('RESPONSE ', response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log('ERROR ', response);
});
```

So I have increased the timeout to 5 seconds.  This still does not help.

If I use POSTMAN I can do a GET to http://localhost:3000/features/123 and it returns the proper data.

In Chrome\Network I see the following:

123
localhost/features | GET | (failed) | Pending | angular.js:11442 Script | 13B | 490 ms

I can actually click on the 124 localhost/features link in the Chrome\Network screen and the GET request works.

My config object is as follows:

```
headers: Object
   Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
method: "GET"
paramSerializer: function ngParamSerializer(params) 
timeout: 5000
tranforRequest : Array[1]
   0: function(d) {
   length : 1
tranforResponse : Array[1]
   0: function defaultHttpResponseTransform(data, headers) {
   length : 1
url: "http//localhost:3000/features/123"
```

I am using AngularJS v1.5.0.

I have seen other posts where it will intermittently work (i.e. sometimes a status code of -1 is returned, other times it works).  I have not seen a successful transaction yet.

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong or where to look next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you serve your angularjs website ? From localhost on another port ? Or from filesystem ?

Comment: I created a simple node express server that serves on localhost:3000

Comment: What is interesting is if I change the URL from my localhost:3000 to say www.google.com the request works.

Comment: Might it be a CORS issue?

Comment: do you get any errors on your node console ? or any CORS error on browser console? 
are you running the angular app on the same server ?

Comment: I will look into this. thanks.

Comment: My server is running on my laptop.  My app is actually an ionic app running on a tablet connected via USB to my laptop.

My laptop and tablet are both connected via Wifi to the same network.

I have a console.log in my server code when it gets a request.  I never see this printed out.

Comment: I do see in Chrome\Network the following:

My timeout is see for 5 seconds, but when I make the request from my tablet, it fails (see in Chrome\network) right away.

In Chrome\Network I have the following Request information on the failed request.

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/features/123

Request Headers
GET http://localhost:3000/features/123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-T235Y Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Comment: Like I mentioned if I change the URL from http://localhost:3000/features/123 to http://www.google.com the request succeeds.

I can also use POSTMAN to make a successful request.

I do not see any errors in my browser besides the following in Chrome\Network

GET | (failed) | Pending | angular.js:11442| 13B | 231 ms